# What is DuckDuckGo and how is it related to Tor browser?

Tags: browsers

I just installed Tor and on the page I see a place to type questions into something called DuckDuckGo,  but not “tor browser”.  Am I missing something?

Comment: duck duck go provides results similar to google and being anonamace makes it very valuable software

Answer (score 1):

[Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) is a [webbrowser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_browser) focused on privacy and anonymous communication.

[DuckDuckGo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DuckDuckGo) is a [web search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_search_engine) which respects your privacy, avoids a filter bubble and even provides a [hidden service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_(anonymity_network)#Hidden_services): http://3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion/

Answer (score 1):

DuckDuckGo is a search engine just like Google. Like Google, DuckDuckGo crawls the web and indexes it and gives you relevant results when you search using it. Unlike Google, DuckDuckGo does not track your activity. Hence, it is well liked by privacy conscious people, for example people who use tor. So that's why the Tor Browser creators selected it as the default search engine instead of Google.

Comment: DuckDuckGo does have its own crawler, its called DuckDuckBot - https://help.duckduckgo.com/duckduckgo-help-pages/results/duckduckbot/