# Difference between Duck and Tor

Tags: support

Can somebody explain to me what is the difference between Duck Duck Go and Tor Browsers? And if I install one I have to uninstall the other?

Comment: DuckDuckGo is a search engine (like Google), and the Tor Browser is a web browser (like Chrome). DuckDuckGo is a website, but they do have a Firefox/Chrome extension you can install. This extension is designed to improve your privacy in the Firefox/Chrome browser, but does not provide anonymity like the Tor Browser tries to. Edit: See https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/17961/24966

Comment: a duplicate of https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/17961/5234